# How can I get a equation of slope?

Tags: camera-calibration

Here are two $x$,$y$ coordinates: $(2,2)$ ,$(4,3)$.
And I want to know if I choose $x$ between above coordinate.
How can I know the $y$?

As I know a slope of line equation is like this.
$$y= mx+b$$

So if I apply the coordinate into above equation.
$$m= \dfrac{3-2}{4-2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$
$$b= 2$$
$$y= \dfrac{1}{2} x + b$$

So if I choose $x$ to be $4$ then I can get a value $4$ not $3$.
I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Your $b=1$. Check it..

Comment: You kidding, right? This is not a DSP question.

Comment: Hmm I don't think so. Becuase my question is from DSP expriment.

Comment: And that obviously doesn't make it fit to the DSP SE.

Comment: So What do you want from me? please tell me directly. why you keep obsession

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general question about simple mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $b$ is wrong. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation). The form $y=mx+b$ is called Slope-Intercept form where $b$ is the intersection with the y-axis (which is 1 in your case). You should use the [two-point form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form):
$$
y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} (x - x_1)
$$

which yields
$$
y - 2 = \frac{1}{2} (x - 2)
$$
or
$$
y = \frac{1}{2} x + 1
$$